# Javascript and jQuery Scripts Have a Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I seem to be gradually adding more and more Javascript and jQuery to my pages, and today it has turned around and bitten me. I have the following scripts in the  of my parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../floatbox/floatbox.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/calendar_min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--Script makes ToDate jump to FromDate
MouseOver = true;
function date_copy_set() {
    FirstMouseOver = true;
}
function date_copy() {
    if (FirstMouseOver && MouseOver) {
        document.bookboxform.DepartureDate.value=document.bookboxform.ArrivalDate.value; // Main form
        frames.booking.DepartureDate.value=frames.booking.ArrivalDate.value; // Prices tab
        FirstMouseOver = false;
        MouseOver = false;
    }else{ }
}
-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function shortlist(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if ( el.value == 'checked') {
        window.location.replace("../favouritesdrop.php?hid=" + id +"&page=<?php echo $full_url ?>");
    }
    else {
        window.location.replace("../favouritesadd.php?hid=" + id +"&page=<?php echo $full_url ?>");
    }
}
</script>
<script>
<!-- Tabs script -->
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabcontent > div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $("#tabcontent div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
            return       
        }
        else{             
            $("#tabcontent > div").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
            $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
            $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
    $('#prices').load('../prices_col.php?hid=<?php echo $hid;?>');
    $("#prices").on('click', 'a.click', function() {
        $(".hiddenstuff").slideToggle(1000),
        $("a.click").toggleClass("faded");
    });
});
</script>
```

The parent page has a tabbed area controlled by the Tabs Script shown above.

One of those tabs contains the file `prices_col.php` which is ajax-loaded by a line of the script above.

`Prices_col.php` contains a hidden area that is revealed by jQuery. The hodden area contains two date boxes that have a date picker calendar which runs from `calendar_min.js`. There is another pair of date boxes in the parent page that also use the date picker.

Everything works fine when the page is newly opened. Dates can be inserted in the main page or in the prices tab, and the calendar works correctly in both. However if I refresh the main page, the calendar no longer works in the prices tab (but still works in the main page). If I clear the browser cache before refreshing the main page everything works properly.

I assume this indicates a conflict somewhere. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Is it possible to make a fiddle, so we can see it in action?

Comment: are you using google chrome? if so you can view the console if any errors have occurred. press `F12` when you're on your page and navigate to the `Console` tab.

Comment: I doubt it's related to the problem, but moving IDs around to different elements is usually a bad idea. Add and remove a class to indicate the current tab.

Comment: @Barmar. Javascript console doesn't show anything significant.
I don't think I'm using IDs to indicate the current tab (if I'm understanding you right). #tabs is the <ul> that encloses all the tabs. They are individually identified by name.

Comment: You're doing `$(this).parent().attr("id","current");` to indicate which tab is current.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird. I'm working on a jsfiddle but it's something else I don't know much about. At the moment I can't work out how to incorporate two html files within one fiddle.

Comment: @Barmar. I see what you mean, but this is code that I copied from elsewhere. It seems to work. As you said, it's unlikely to be related to the present problem which seems to be happening deep inside the tab.

Comment: If you need multiple html files for your example, you could try http://plnkr.co/ However, I'd first try simplifying the problem. Maybe jQuery loading the second file into the first has nothing to do with the problem; so insert that html manually and remove the line of jQuery to see if it makes a difference. If it doesn't make a difference, you only need one html file for the example, and otherwise we've learned something more about the problem.

Comment: Good idea, @towr. And the answer is.......... we've learned something more about the problem. Combining the second file (prices_col.php) into the parent file and deleting the line that ajax-loads it has made the problem go away.

So now I must think about what conclusion I can draw from that. Well, not now because it's getting late and I have to be up early in the morning.

If I don't have any other solution, I'll have to decide whether keeping the whole lot together in one file is a suitable solution. I'll run it through webpagetest.org and see what the impact on loading times is.

Comment: @towr. Page loading speed actually seems slightly faster by piling all the content into one file. So there is no reason why I should attempt to ajax-load part of it. Tomorrow I'll move the whole site over to doing it all in one file. The original problem still bugs me though.

Comment: Yeah, it's an odd problem how it work on the first load but not after refresh. But you'll need to post more information if you want help figuring it out. Do you have the problem in all browsers?

Comment: @towr. To be honest I haven't tried it with other browsers: I normally use the latest Firefox which generally doesn't throw up any unique problems of it's own. Anyway I've followed through your suggestion of putting everything into one file and it has allowed me to streamline the mySQL queries, so altogether I think it's a better solution than the ajax route that I was trying to use.